# Creating a System Defined Object (Enum)

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is it possible to create what I can best describe as a system defined object in VB.Net on VS2010? I have included as picture from the color class describing the functionality I was wondering about.

[image]

Also, if there is a better name for this please let me know so I can rename the question.

Comment: That looks like an `Enum`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Enum Color
    Red
    Orange
    Yellow
    Green
    Blue
    Purple
End Enum
```

Answer (score 1):

An `Enum` is more or less a type declaration with members that are aliases to numeric values.

In the example from your question, the `Color` type is a `Structure` (a value type), and the different options you see for available colors are actually `Shared` Properties defined in the `Structure`. The reason it is done this way and not as an `Enum` is because the `Color` type is not a numeric type.

For example, if you wanted to make a Color class of your own, it would look like:

```
Public Structure MyColor
    Property Red as Byte
    Property Green as Byte
    Property Blue as Byte

    Sub New(r as Byte, g as Byte, b as Byte)
        Red = r
        Green = g
        Blue = b
    End Sub

    Shared ReadOnly Property BrightRed as MyColor
        Get
            Return New Color(255,0,0)
        End Get
    End Property
End Structure
```

In the above example, BrightRed would show up as an option when you type "`MyColor.`" in the code editor.

Comment: This make a lot of sense, I will play around with this some.